# Pegar informações de um array dentro de um foreach - PHP

Tags: php, array, laravel, foreach

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com PHP usando o Laravel, e estou com uma dificuldade.

Tenho uma tabela com o nome de Conta, no qual possui o código dessa conta, representado pela variável `$cliente->Codigo`, possui também o CNPJ do cliente e a razão social representado pela variável `$cliente->ClienteRazao`.

Eu criei um array de CPNJ's de clientes.
Estou dando um select na tabela no qual se encontra as informações desses clientes, e de acordo com o cnpj do array, eu quero pegar as informações desse cliente para inserí-las no meu insert.

Atualmente o meu insert está funcionando, mas a variável `$cliente->Codigo` está sendo inserida o valor de 1 para todos os clientes (cada cliente tem um código unico) e o `$cliente->ClienteRazao` não vem nada. Estou fazendo algo de errado, mas não sei o que é.

Link para a imagem do código bonitinha no visual code para melhor visualização:
[Link imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfaZb.png)

OBS: a variável `$data->Nfse->InfNfse->TomadorServico->IdentificacaoTomador->CpfCnpj->Cnpj` que está no `if`, é o campo `CNPJ` vindo de um arquivo JSON.

Segue o código:

```
//select na tabela Conta, no qual consta todas as informações dos clientes
(cnpj, código, razão social etc..)

$pesquisaClientes = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->select('SELECT * FROM 
ConsultaCnpj.dbo.Conta');

    // array dos CNPJ's dos clientes
    $CnpjClientes = array("43185230000185", "43037969000140", "52391703000191", "00697722000147", "35259696000150", "14189856000161", "11684590000135",
    "00299388000173", "12515276000191", "73800260000115", "26562892000108", "04711149000130", "11888864000108", "24193260000199", "34482091000160", 
    "10638562000119", "15615776000193", "22165071000187", "02505297000172", "03662446000170", "07863214000130", "34639419000100", "26619841000175", 
    "13738204000176", "62021837000174", "24417008000116", "11005444000136", "08303182000181", "84318799000159", "04768671000158", "00593411000138", 
    "06572788000197", "03875295000138", "08332733000135", "00237222000122", "06272868000127", "08336841000186", "04734406000159", "07647181000191", 
    "04769874000169", "08506339000176", "27149095000166", "34476101000155", "84042423000164", "13161344000124", "26753715000109", "23498256000176", 
    "00577473000156", "11425519000138", "90601147000120", "08077490000136", "04185220000198", "01646861000104", "02116365000101", "05379164000195", 
    "56319882000107", "15678394000109", "00581009000133", "08641589000119", "34918342000107", "11674272000193", "07801011000110", "30892350000170", 
    "87070843000142", "10456659000100", "44407989000128", "10338929000189", "06186786000160", "11674751000100", "08299638000187", "06274668000103", 
    "11578277000112", "73603748000152", "73392409000174", "05644027000130", "56321573000171", "60993482000150", "00085803000196", "870000000000196", 
    "57352635000175", "33658204000173");
    
    foreach ($pesquisaClientes as $cliente) {

            if (in_array($data->Nfse->InfNfse->TomadorServico->IdentificacaoTomador->CpfCnpj->Cnpj, $CnpjClientes)) {

                //insert conta de debito (cliente)
                DB::insert('insert into LancaContaContabil (Codigo, DataOper, DespRateio, Valor, Receita, AgenteCobrador, 
                DespHistorico, Complemento, Orcado, Encerrado, CodigoContaContabil, LoteLanca,
                Rascunho, DC) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 
                array($ult+1, $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Competencia, NULL, $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Valores->ValorServicos,
                0, NULL, 9182, $numero_nota . ', ' . $cliente->ClienteRazao, 0, 0, $cliente->Codigo, $lanca, 0, 'D'));
                
            }
```

Comment: compartilha o output da variável `$cliente`

Comment: E aí 13dev, beleza? O output da variável $cliente->ClienteRazao é null e da variável $cliente->Codigo é sempre 1

Comment: mostra o output do objecto ex: `print_r($cliente);`

Comment: O output do $cliente é esse: `stdClass Object ( [Numero] => 1.0.0.00.00 [Denominacao] => ATIVO [NumeroReduzido] => 17 [Codigo] => 1 [Cnpj] => [ClienteRazao] => )` Essas informações são do primeiro registro da minha tabela, alguma coisa tá errada, era pra ele pegar essas informações de acordo com o CNPJ que está no array e na tabela. Mas o meu array no qual consta os CNPJ's dos clientes não está sendo levado em consideração

Comment: penso que o erro estará na variável `$pesquisaClientes`, contendo só um registo, verifica isso

Comment: opa, esse teste eu já tinha feito... ta tudo ok com o $pesquisaClientes, tá vindo a minha tabela inteira, sem nenhum problema

Comment: resolvi o problema! Eu estava dando o foreach errado, era para iterar no array das minhas notas fiscais que estavam vindo de um json. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Se você resolveu o problema poste uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Poste uma resposta fjurr, isso ajuda a comunidade a crescer, além de que sua pergunta vai sair da categoria 'Sem respostas'.

Comment: Tem 3 coisas que não fazem sentido para mim, vc está percorrendo todos os dados do banco, para inserir apenas 1 registro, isso se ele tiver no seu array de cnpj, e depois vc está criando uma ID numérica sem consulta, o que não faz sentido algum: `$ult+1`, o que liga o cnpj ao dado da consulta? O que tem dentro desse: `$pesquisaClientes`?

Comment: Você está usando uma coleção `$pesquisaClientes`, com um alias `$cliente` e fazendo a referência como `$data` ?

Answer (score -3):

Man! Assim se você está utilizando laravel, semanticamente falando, a melhor forma de fazer isso seria você criar uma Model e uma migration de clientes, dessa forma você chama um metódo get() ou find() da classe cliente com o método where('cnpj','=','38748578000137') e você vai pegar todos os dados da entidade cliente que você precisa.